# слова "год", "годы" при написании даты в круглых скобках

Tags: даты, скобки

Помогите, пожалуйста. В круглых скобках слова и сокращения "год" и "года" опускаются - (2013), (2001-2003) и т. д. А что делать, когда в скобках есть еще и слова? Например:
(издана в 1995);
(октябрь 1998 - ноябрь 1999);
(с 2003);
(12 июня 2021).